# Create array from MySQL PDO query results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have the table "users" :

```
________________________________________________
|---ID---|---Email---|---Birthday---|---City---|
|---1----|asd@asd.as-|-02/03/1989---|---NY-----|
|---2----|asq@avt.al-|-06/01/1990---|---LA-----|
------------------------------------------------
```

This is the query i use in pdo :

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM users";
```

What i want is to stock the result from mysql pdo query in an array variable like this:

```
$result = array(
   array("id"=>1,
    "email"=>"asd@asd.as".
    "birthday"=>"02/03/1989",
    "city"=>"NY"),
   array("id"=>2,
    "email"=>"asq@avt.al".
    "birthday"=>"06/01/1990",
    "city"=>"LA")
);
```

How can i insert all the results in an array like this in php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          ^^^^^ or whatever you use
```